# The meaning of "cast" in this quote

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What is the exact meaning and concept of "cast" in this quote?

> “When you have once seen the glow of happiness on the face of a
>   beloved person, you know that a man can have no vocation but to awaken
>   that light on the faces surrounding him; and you are torn by the
>   thought of the unhappiness and night you **cast**, by the mere fact of
>   living, in the hearts you encounter.”
>
> ―*Albert Camus*

Comment: [Sense 2, given that "night" and "shadow" are nearly synonymous](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20cast).

Answer (score 1):

This is extending the metaphor of "that light", conceiving "the unhappiness and night" (the latter a further metaphor) as a shadow which you cast.